# SDL_RenderCopy not doing anything

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-image

I'm calling SDL_RenderCopy and it gets called and returns normally but doesn't draw anything to the window. Edited to make the question and code clearer. I'm thinking I might be trying to use something beyond its scope and hence it can't be called but this doesn't produce any error so I'm not sure. Here's the simple picture I refer to https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:PNG_chess_pieces/Standard_transparent#/media/File:Chess_kdt60.png

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

// Recreation of the problem. Doesnt draw anything onto the white screen.

class King{

public:
  King(SDL_Renderer *renderer){
    SDL_Surface *Piece;
    Piece = IMG_Load("Pieces/BK.png"); // I'll attach the picture
    king = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Piece);
    SDL_FreeSurface(Piece);
    kingRect.h = 100;
    kingRect.w = 100;
  }
  ~King(){}

  void render(SDL_Renderer *renderer){
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, king, NULL, &kingRect); // 99% sure the     problem is this
  }

private:
  SDL_Texture *king;
  SDL_Rect kingRect;
};

class Game {

 public:
  Game(const char *title, int sidelength){
    isRunning = true;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) isRunning = false;

window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,   SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, sidelength, sidelength, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
if(window == NULL) isRunning = false;

renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
if(!renderer) isRunning = false;

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
  }
  ~Game(){}
  void handleEvents(){
    //Handles Events. I know this works.
    }
  }

  void update(){};

  void render(){
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    BK.render(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  }

  void clean(){
    //Cleans up after. I know this works.
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
  }
  bool running(){return(isRunning);}
  King BK{renderer};
private:
  bool isRunning{true};
  SDL_Window *window;
  SDL_Renderer *renderer;
};

Game *game = nullptr;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
  game = new Game("Testing Window", 800);

  while(game->running()){
    game->handleEvents();
    game->update();
    game->render();
  }
  game->clean();
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: This isn't nearly enough code to tell where the bug is coming from. Are you checking return values from SDL functions and checking [`SDL_GetError()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError) when something fails? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53384197/edit) your question to include information to reproduce the problem, and consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for bringing the lack of clarity to my attention. I created a mini program that reproduces the same problem. SDL_GetError doesn't find any error which was part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks! This looks much better. I suspect that `kingRect.x` and `kingRect.y` are uninitialized and might have garbage values, which could place the target rectangle somewhere really far off screen. Try adding `kingRect.x = 0; kingRect.y = 0;` in your constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`King BK{renderer};` field gets initialised before your `Game::Game` finishes and gets a chance to assign a renderer, so it gets `NULL` instead. `NULL` is not a valid renderer and can't create textures. If you would have checked for error you would have got `Invalid renderer` message. Also decent compiler with enabled warnings will tell something like `warning: 'Game::renderer' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`; consider enabling better warning levels in your compiler.

Second thing is that you never called `IMG_Init` with required image formats you intend to load.

Third thing is that code is misformatted and wouldn't compile without modifications. I suggest testing code that you post as MCCVE for still being compilable and reproducing your problem (as MCCVE implies).

Comment: Thanks. It seems like there were two problems.The first is what you described in your first paragraph and the second was that even though I called IMG_LOAD with a path to the picture it wouldn't be loaded. So I moved the png right beside the actual code for this project and then it would load.